# Hover over div to reveal nested span with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I thought this would work outright, but I must be missing something.

I have a nested `span` of content in a div and I'm trying to get that span to show on hover (and hide on mouseout).

I thought that just doing a `$(this).find('.name-of-span') inside of a`hover` function would do it, but something must be missing.

This is what I have:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="parent-item">
    <h3>title 01</h3>
        <span class="meta--reveal">
          <a class="btn" href="#">Link</a>
        </span>
</div>

<div class="parent-item">
        <h3>title 02</h3>
            <span class="meta--reveal">
              <a class="btn" href="#">Link</a>
            </span>
    </div>
```

**JS:**

```
  $('.parent-item').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.meta--reveal').show();
  });
```

I thought that *should* work, but again, I'm probably missing something.

I also tried to do this with CSS with an adjacent sibling selector, but that wasn't working either.

Comment: Your javascript attempt, was the issue that it was showing the child, but not hiding it after you leave the hover state?  Because you've given it the method for the hover start, but not the method for the hover end to revert the show

Comment: See my answer.  Your logic works.  You're just missing the secondary function for the hover.

Answer (score 3):

You can construct a CSS rule that only hides the nested element if the parent is not hovered.

```css
.parent-item:not(:hover) .meta--reveal {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-item">
  <h3>title 01</h3>
  <span class="meta--reveal">
    <a class="btn" href="#">Link</a>
  </span>
</div>

<div class="parent-item">
  <h3>title 02</h3>
  <span class="meta--reveal">
    <a class="btn" href="#">Link</a>
  </span>
</div>
```

Otherwise, your existing logic **does** work.  You're just missing the second method that reverts the show.

```js
  $('.parent-item').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.meta--reveal').show();
  }, function(){
    $(this).find('.meta--reveal').hide();
  });
```

```css
.parent-item .meta--reveal {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent-item">
  <h3>title 01</h3>
  <span class="meta--reveal">
    <a class="btn" href="#">Link</a>
  </span>
</div>

<div class="parent-item">
  <h3>title 02</h3>
  <span class="meta--reveal">
    <a class="btn" href="#">Link</a>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. It's weird cause the CSS method isn't working for me for some reason. But that's what happens when you inherit a project that you didn't work on from the start. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

this is working. First, the going to show element must be 'display: none'.

```js
  $('.parent-item').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.meta--reveal').show();
  });
```

```css
.meta--reveal {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-item">
    <h3>title 01</h3>
        <span class="meta--reveal">
          <a class="btn" href="#">Link</a>
        </span>
</div>

<div class="parent-item">
        <h3>title 02</h3>
            <span class="meta--reveal">
              <a class="btn" href="#">Link</a>
            </span>
 </div>
    
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```

Also usable `children()` instead of `find()`

Answer (score 0):

Hide all the link before displaying the selected one.

```
$('.parent-item').hover(function() {
    //hide all the link before displaying the selected one. 
    $('.meta--reveal').hide();
    //displays the selected  item
    $(this).find('.meta--reveal').show();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to add and remove classes to toggle display, teamed up with the '.children' for targeted selection

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".hover").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).children('.target').removeClass("hide").addClass("reveal");
});

$(".hover").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).children('.target').removeClass("reveal").addClass("hide");
});

});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.reveal {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="hover">
  <h3>title 01</h3>
  <div class="target hide">
  <span class="metaReveal"><a class="btn" href="#">Link</a></span>
</div>
</div>  



<div class="hover">
  <h3>title 02</h3>
<div class="target hide">
  <span class="metaReveal"><a class="btn" href="#">Link</a></span>
</div>
</div>
```